# Form implementation

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have one form with some input text with the name = "user_name" , "mob" , "email" and inside this form i have a link for example Plans and end with submit button. Now if user click the link then i want to have all the values of the input text of the same form send to another page to pks.php and if the user click on the submit button then it will work on action confirm.php. For example Check this code

```html
<form action="confirm.php" method ="post">
<input type ="text" name="user_name">
<input type="number" name="mob">
<input type="text" name="email">
<a href="pks.php">PLANS</a>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Can you help me out?? How can i achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a file called confirm.php in the same directory, what error do you get when you click on submit button ?

Comment: Thats what the submit button is for

Comment: i am not getting any error. I want when i click on link the value of text boxes also passes with the link to pks.php

Comment: if the link is clicked the value of the text box should go to the pks,php and if button is clicked the value of text box should go to the confirm.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the link to a second submit button. You can then use the `formaction` attribute to change the URL the form submits to when you use this button.

```html
<form action="confirm.php" method ="post">
<input type ="text" name="user_name">
<input type="number" name="mob">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" formaction="pks.php" value="PLANS">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you can't do that, you need to run Javascript when they click on the link. You can have this code change the action of the form, and then submit it.

```js
document.getElementById('plans').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.getElementById('myform');
  form.action = this.href;
  form.submit();
});
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="confirm.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user_name">
  <input type="number" name="mob">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <a id="plans" href="pks.php">PLANS</a>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use JavaScript to control the form if you want the action attribute to change. By default, submitting the form will cause it to post to `confirm.php`.

Using JQuery you can do this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // Stop the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do logic to determine what action you should do
    var myAction = 'pks.php';

    // assign the action to the form
    $(this).attr('action', myAction);

    // submit the form
    $(this).submit();
});
```

I haven't run this script so it may not work out of the box but you should be able to adapt and fix it without too much difficulty.

Comment: Clicking a link doesn't trigger the `submit` event.

Comment: You didn't get my question properly i dont want to prevent the default function of the form, I just want if the link is clicked the value of input text should also pass with the link.

Comment: And i don't want action attribute to change.

Comment: @PiyushSahay Why does it matter if the attribute changes? The page goes away when it gets submitted.